# Warning: The plugin permission_handler_android requires Android SDK version 33

Tags: android, flutter

I just started seeing the following warning when building my Flutter project:

```
Warning: The plugin permission_handler_android requires Android SDK version 33.
For more information about build configuration, see https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/android#reviewing-the-build-configuration.
One or more plugins require a higher Android SDK version.
Fix this issue by adding the following to C:\Users\roger\Source\choon\player\android\app\build.gradle:
android {
  compileSdkVersion 33
  ...
}
```

My `build.gradle` contains the following:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion flutter.compileSdkVersion
...
```

What caused this, and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

This was caused by a recent change to the `permission_handler` plugin; see [the Changelog](https://pub.dev/packages/permission_handler/changelog):

> **BREAKING CHANGE**: Updated Android compileSdkVersion to 33 to handle the new `POST_NOTIFICATIONS` permission.

The official [Build Numbers](https://source.android.com/setup/start/build-numbers) only go up to API Level 32 (*Android 12L*), but [apilevels.com](https://apilevels.com/) shows that API Level 33 is *Android 13 Beta*.

You have two options:

1. Change `compileSdkVersion flutter.compileSdkVersion` to `compileSdkVersion 33`, which targets Android SDK 33. You can also do this by writing `flutter.compileSdkVersion = 33` after the existing `apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"` line. At the time of this answer (Flutter 3.0.2), `flutter.compileSdkVersion` is 31.
2. Roll back to `permission_handler` 9.x, by editing `pubspec.yaml` as follows:

```
dependencies:
  ...
  permission_handler: ^9.2.0
  ...
```

Comment: Rolling back might always be better than the 1st option, because currently, some official flutter plugins misbehaves when compileSdkVersion is set to 33, in my case, it was the camera plugin.

Comment: If I change it to `compileSdkVersion 33`, does that mean the application will not work on devices with previous Android versions?

Comment: @best_of_man, no for previous android versions minSdkVersion is used and defines min android version

Answer (score 0):

Change this

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion flutter.compileSdkVersion
```

with this

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 33
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?

Answer (score 0):

In your flutter project under `android` directory, there exists two `build.gradle`file. remember the `build.gradle` path is under the `android/app/src` directory, not the `android/` directory, i have spend much time to the confirm the `build.gradle` path

[image]