# Flutter run stuck at installing when using compileSdkVersion=33

Tags: android, flutter

I noticed these kind of warnings when running my Flutter app:

> One or more plugins require a higher Android SDK version.
>
> Warning: The plugin geolocator_android requires Android SDK version
> 33. For more information about build configuration, see https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/android#reviewing-the-build-configuration.
> Warning: The plugin mobile_scanner requires Android SDK version 32.
> For more information about build configuration, see
> https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/android#reviewing-the-build-configuration.

So I tried upgrading to Android SDK version 33.
I changed the versions to this in `android/local.properties`:

> flutter.minSdkVersion=23
> flutter.targetSdkVersion=33
> flutter.compileSdkVersion=33

and I access these values in `android/app/build.gradle` like this:

```
localProperties.getProperty('flutter.compileSdkVersion').toInteger()
```

In `android/build.gradle`:

```
//...
dependencies {
    //...
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.1.2'

}
//...
```

In `android/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties`:

```
//...
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.4-all.zip
```

**Now running the command `flutter run --verbose`**

With compileSdkVersion set to 32 the app builds and runs.
With compileSdkVersion set to 33 however it stucks forever at:

> [ +101 ms] Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.RUN
> flg=0x20000000 cmp=app.myapp/.MainActivity (has extras) } Error type 3
> Error: Activity class {app.myapp/app.myapp.MainActivity} does not exist.
> [        ] Waiting for observatory port to be available...

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72697570/10157127) might help you

Comment: They say either downgrade the package or upgrade the sdk. Cannot downgrade.

Comment: Did you have any luck? Facing the same thing with React Native.

Answer (score 0):

What's your flutter version? I had the same error (MainActivity does not exist) and upgrade my Flutter version to 3.3.2. It works fine now.

Answer (score 0):

I also upgraded my compilsSdkVersion to 33  and it ran and get closed when i try to run in debug mode so i did following things

1. I upgraded the flutter to latest 3.3.2 (may be) as suggested above
2. I use flutter clean (I think this work)
   And it began to run smoothly
   Thanks

Answer (score 0):

ok, what I did was:

1. Update all packages to see if all of them are already for SDK version 31/32/33
2. (In my case it's Flutter) I had to update Flutter version at least 3.3.2
3. `flutter clean`
4. and change version on build.gradle/app to `'androidx.work:work-runtime:2.7.1'`